# When playing around with columns and width leaves characters hanging outside columnwidth

Tags: redraw

I was playing around with setting `columns` and then turning `wrap` on&off.

The screenshot actually shows an empty buffer. To reproduce:`set columns=80 number`, make a huuuuge line of i-s and turn wrap on and off. With `vim -u NONE` as in the screenshot it felt it's a bit harder to reproduce than in my normally configured version but still happens. Any idea why? Is this a known bug or something that I can prevent?

[image]

Comment: I can reproduce with my regular vimrc, but not if I use the default settings with `vim -Nu NONE`, so it seems affected by some other setting, too. If you can make it reproduce with `vim -Nu NONE` you can file a bug on the Vim issue tracker.

Comment: I don't follow. Is this an empty buffer or not (filled with `i`s)? What version? What terminal?

Comment: Terminal is `kitty 0.25.0`, vim is `9.0`. The screenshot is an empty buffer AFTER I filled it with a ton of i-s (single line), flipped wrap a few times and then deleted the line.

Comment: Didn't know about the `-N` option, but I'll check with that as well, and then maybe try to incrementally figure out if it is one of my settings.

Comment: `-N` is `set nocompatible`; just gives you slightly more modern defaults for various settings that are not compatible with vi from 70s/80s.